# Task Dependency in OpenMP 4

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, dependencies, task, openmp

The following code works based on the OpenMP 4.0 specification:

> The out and ***inout*** dependence-types. The generated task will be a
>   dependent task of all previously generated sibling tasks that
>   reference at least one of the list items in an in, out, or inout
>   dependence-type list.

This means that task3 becomes dependent of task2. Right? but it does not make sense! Why should an input-output dependency task be a dependent of an input dependency task?

What do I need to do in order to make them independent?
p.s: code tested with g++ 4.9 on Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
int x,y;
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(10)
{
#pragma omp single nowait
 {
#pragma omp task depend (out:x)  //task1
  {
        x=1;
  }
#pragma omp task depend(in:x) depend(out:y)  //task2
  {
        sleep(2); //Does task3 wait for us? Yes!
        y=x+1;
  }
#pragma omp task depend (inout:x)  //task3
  {
        x++;
        printf("task3(x): %d\n" , x);
  }
#pragma omp task depend (in:x,y)  //task4
 {
        printf("task4 (x+y): %d\n" , x+y);
 }
 }
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Question 1** : *This means that task3 becomes dependent of task2. Right?*

According to the [OpenMP 4.0](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf) standard on the `depend` clause (emphasis mine):

> Task dependences are derived from the dependence-type of a `depend`
>   clause and its list items, where dependence-type is one of the
>   following:
>
> The **in** dependence-type. The generated task will be a **dependent
>   task of** all previously generated sibling tasks that reference at
>   least one of the list items in an **out or inout dependence-type
>   list**.
>
> The **out and inout** dependence-types. The generated task will be a
>   **dependent task of** all previously generated sibling tasks that reference at least one of the list items in an
>   **in, out, or inout dependence-type list**.

From this description follows that:

- the clause `depend(in:x)` will generate a task dependent on all the previously generated tasks with `depend(out:x)` or `depend(inout:x)`
- the clause `depend(out:x)` or the clause `depend(inoout:x)` will generate a task dependent on all the previously generated tasks mentioning `x` in a `depend` clause

Applying this to your specific case gives a chain of dependencies of this kind:

```
       task1 (out:x) -> task2 (in:x,out:y) -> task4 (in:x,y)
                                   |            ^
                                   |            |
                                   > task3 (inout:x)
```

Therefore **task3 depends on the completion of task2**.

---

**Question 2** : *Why should an input-output dependency task be a dependent of an input dependency task?*

I would just let you notice that with this rule you will have a deterministic value of your variables `x` and `y` at the end of the run (assuming you take care of synchronizing accesses to memory). If task3 was dependent on task1 instead of task2, this determinism wouldn't hold (and an `inout` dependency would have been equivalent to an `in` dependency).

---

**Question 3** : *What do I need to do in order to make them independent?*

Turn the `inout:x` dependency into an `in:x` dependency and synchronize accesses to `x` via `atomic` clauses. That way you will have runs in which either:

- `x == 2` and `y == 2`
- `x == 2` and `y == 3`

depending on whether task2 executes before task3 or not.

Comment: Great Explanation. Thank you! So, at the end, this means that inout and out are treated quite the same way. right? They can be used interchangeably!

Comment: @towi_parallelism I think you are correct regarding the behavior of inout and out. Even in the OpenMP 5.0 spec, I couldn't find a place where inout is different from out honestly.