# Task for matrix-vector multiplication and adding by openmp parallel

Tags: openmp, matrix-multiplication

I would like to compute the following matrix-vector multiplication and adding operation as

> `y = (A + C + C^T + R + R^T + D1 + D1^T + D2 + D2^T)x`

Can I use the tasking parallel in openmp to accelerate this operation? The code is as follow

```
    y.setZero();
    int ny = y.size();
#pragma omp parallel shared(x)
{
#pragma omp single
    {
        VectorXd yA(ny),yC(ny), yCt(ny), yR(ny), yRt(ny), yD1(ny), yD1t(ny), yD2(ny), yD2t(ny);
        yA.setZero();
        yC.setZero();
        yCt.setZero();
        yR.setZero();
        yRt.setZero();
        yD1.setZero();
        yD1t.setZero();
        yD2.setZero();
        yD2t.setZero();

    #pragma omp task
        yA = A * x;
    #pragma omp task
        yC = C * x;
    #pragma omp task
        yCt = C.transpose() * x;
    #pragma omp task
        yR = R * x;
    #pragma omp task
        yRt = R.transpose() * x;
    #pragma omp task
        yD1 = D1 * x;
    #pragma omp task
        yD1t = D1.transpose() * x;
    #pragma omp task
        yD2 = D2 * x;
    #pragma omp task
        yD2t = D2.transpose() * x;

    #pragma omp taskwait
        y = yA + yC + yCt + yR + yRt + yD1 + yD1t + yD2 + yD2t;
    }
};
```

This code is based on the Eigen library. Compared with not using the openmp, I can not observe a noticeable acceleration in my computer. But I think it can be paralleled by openmp. So I ask this question. I would appreciate if anybody can answer my question.

Comment: This seems fine to me. The vectors needs to be pretty big so to get a speed-up. Besides this, you need to enable OpenMP with compiler flags. Finally, the operation might be already parallel or just memory-bound regarding your environment/platform.

Comment: Thanks. The size of vectors in my problem is about one hundred million to one billion. I think it is very big. And I have use the "-fopenmp" as the complier flag. I do not know whether the operation is already parallel. I think it is worth observation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use the tasking parallel in openmp to accelerate this operation? The code is as follow
> Blockquote

Yes.
Though in your code, I can see 3 things to improve.

**1) Data sharing** -
When starting with OpenMP, I recommend using `default(none), shared(...) or firstprivate(...)` explicitely on your tasks - so you understand how your variable are actually copied.

**2) Scaling** -
In term of performances, your code will not scales above 9 cores, since you only express 9 tasks.
When doing algebra, you can taskify applications through block operations.
For instance, you can split `A = B + C` into 4 independant block operations *(using Eigen interface...)*

- A(0, 0, n/2, n/2) = B(0, 0, n/2, n/2) + C(0, 0, n/2, n/2)
- A(0, n/2, n/2, n/2) = B(0, n/2, n/2, n/2) + C(0, n/2, n/2, n/2)
- A(n/2, 0, n/2, n/2) = B(n/2, 0, n/2, n/2) + C(n/2, 0, n/2, n/2)
- A(n/2, n/2, n/2, n/2) = B(n/2, n/2, n/2, n/2) + C(n/2, n/2, n/2, n/2)

The block size here is `n/2` and defines your [tasks granularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granularity_(parallel_computing))

**3) Synchronousity** -
To ensure correct order of execution, you used a `# pragma omp taskwait` - which is an explicit barrier that waits for completion of previously spawned tasks.
Since OpenMP 4.0, tasks can have [dependences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475174/task-dependency-in-openmp-4) to guarantee order of execution on a finer level.

**Mixing things up** -
I made a micro-benchmark with 3 versions of your problem - [source](https://pastebin.com/pnk6C6fN)

- sequential - the computation is done on 1 core
- taskwait - your version
- block - that uses Eigen block operations, and OpenMP dependences.
  I splited the computation into 2 operations and taskified each operations with `m` blocks.

  - `add` - `M := A + C + C^T + R + R^T + D1 + D1^T + D2 + D2^T`
  - `mult` - `y := M.x`
    On this figure, is the dependency task graph for `m=2` - the `add(0, 0)` task works on the top-left block, the `add(1, 0)` task works on the top-right block, etc... - the `mult` tasks depends from the `add` tasks working on the same line of blocks - the `norm` task is a correctness check.

[image]

I run it on 16 cores, with `n=4,096` and `m=16` (n° of blocks per line-wise operation). Here is my result

> sequential version took 1.28707 s.
> taskwait version took 0.177616 s.(SUCCESS)
> task version took 0.128707 s.(SUCCESS)

I run it again, but on 64 cores this time, and with `m=64`

> sequential version took 1.31316 s.
> taskwait version took 0.170817 s.(SUCCESS)
> task version took 0.0785489 s.(SUCCESS)

The "block version" scales with cores, but the "taskwait" version does not.

Here is the Gantt chart of the 1st execution (`m=16`).
The big blue task correspond to the sequential-version execution, the red ones to the taskwait-version execution. The purple and pink tasks correspond respectively to the `add` and `mult` tasks of the block-version.

As you can see, the taskwait-version only uses 9 cores out of 16, while the block-version can use every cores.

[image]

a zoom on the block-version, and enabling dependences rendering with arrows

[image]

*The figures were generated using [Multi-Processor-Computing (MPC)](https://mpc.hpcframework.com/) - which implements an OpenMP runtime and tracing tools.*

Comment: Thank you so much! I have learned a lot from your answer. I think I need to optimize my code again. As for the block operation,  actually, in my problem, I do not have the explicit form of each matrix. I just have the function to compute the matrix-vector multiplication. This is why I would like to use the task parallelization to accelerate my program.  Thank you again!